# increment css property value using loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I place below line of code within a loop,

```
for ( var i=1; i<=10; i++ ) {

var left = 0;
    left += 20;

$('#item'+i).css({
        'left': left
    });
}
```

how can I make left value increment by 20? currently all is set to 20, it won't increase by 20.

Answer (score 1):

```
var left = 0;

for ( var i=1; i<=10; i++ ) {

left += 20;

$('#item'+i).css({ 'left': left }); }
```

Everytime you go in the loop, var left is initialized to 0. Thus your value will always be 20.
move the initialization outside the loop. It should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, you need to **get** css left first, then increment and assign it:

```
for ( var i=1; i<=10; i++ ) {
  var left = $('#item'+i).css('left');
  left.replace("px", ""); //remove "px" from left. for example, convert "30px" to "30"
  left = parseInt(left); //convert to integer
  left += 20;
  $('#item'+i).css({ 'left': left+"px" }); 
}
```